# Passing params in a helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have, on my Miniature model view page the following code

```
<%= content_setmini_links_with_quantity(@miniature) %>
```

It refers to this miniatures_helper method

```
def content_setmini_links_with_quantity(miniature)
  miniature.reverse_contents.map{|content| content_setmini_link_with_quantity(content)}.join(' ').html_safe
end
```

Which in turn references this miniatures_helper method

```
def content_setmini_link_with_quantity(content)
  string = (tag "td"), (link_to top_pic(content.setmini_id), content.setmini), (link_to content.setmini.name, content.setmini)
  string << " x#{content.quantity}" if content.quantity.present?
  return string
end
```

This is supposed to reference the final miniatures_helper method

```
def top_pic
  @miniature = Miniature.find(params[:setmini_id])
  if @miniature.collections.first.photo != nil 
    image_tag(@miniature.collections.first.photo.url(:icon), :retina => true, :class => "curvediconminiset")
  else
    image_tag("https://system/stock/blank.gif", :retina => true, :class => "curvediconminiset")
  end
end
```

but I can't work out how to call top_pic correctly.
As far as I can see in `content_setmini_link_with_quantity(content)` the only param available is content. `Content.setmini_id` is the param I want to use to find the `@miniature` to display but I can't get it to work.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling

```
top_pic(content.setmini_id)
```

But your `top_pic` method definition does not have a parameter defined.

Change the definition and first line of `top_pic` to

```
def top_pic(setmini_id)
  @miniature = Miniature.find(setmini_id)
```

and forget about using `params` in a helper.

Comment: Ah I see. In a helper each method has one defined parameter and you can't use params. Thank you. I'm now getting "undefined method `photo' for nil:NilClass" error but I think that's another problem and you've answered the question. Getting stuck at every stage with this today.